# How to save chat message to MongoDB ans send back to client with socketio and Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, socket.io

I am sending private messages to specific user and receiving back the message but when I refresh the page the messages are disappearing. Probably I need to save them to DB but I don't know how to do that.:

**CLIENT:**

```
const [chatHistory, setChatHistory] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connection established!");
    });
    socket.on("loggedin", () => {
      console.log("you're logged in!");
      setLoggedIn(true);
      fetchOnlineUsers();
      socket.on("newConnection", () => {
        console.log("watch out! a new challenger appears!");
        fetchOnlineUsers();
      });
    });

    socket.on("message", (newMessage) => {
      console.log("a new message appeared!", newMessage);
      setChatHistory((chatHistory) => [...chatHistory, newMessage]);
    });
  }, []);
```

**SERVER:**

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.id)
    socket.on("setUsername", ({ username, room }) => {
        console.log(username)

        onlineUsers.push({ username, id: socket.id, room })
        socket.join(room)
        console.log(socket.rooms)
        socket.emit("loggedin")
        // Emits to the other end of *every other* channel
        socket.broadcast.emit("newConnection")

        // Emits to every connected socket
        // io.sockets.emit() 
    })

    socket.on("sendmessage", ({ message, room }) => {
    *Here i need to save messages to DB and send back to client with emit()*
        console.log(message)
        const msg = new MsgModel({sender:message.sender, text: message.text, socketId:message.socketId})
        msg.save()
        console.log("MSG",msg);

        // Emits only to people inside of the defined "room"
        socket.to(room).emit("message", msg)
    })

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        onlineUsers = onlineUsers.filter(user => user.id !== socket.id)
        socket.broadcast.emit("disconnectedUser")
    })

});
```

**MongoDB SCHEMA**
Here is my db schema:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
const { Schema, model } = mongoose;
const msgSchema = new Schema(
  {
    text: { type: String },
    sender: { type: String },
    socketId: { type: String }
  },
  { typeKey: '$type' }
);
export default model("Message", msgSchema);
```

If any code detail need let me know

Comment: Please don't write normal sentences in all upper-case. That's considered shouting, and that's rather rude.

Comment: Sorry didn know that

Comment: You don't need actually a DB for that.  
I suggest for testing use a rolling file.  
Introduce message synchronization mechanism, any chat system uses  
 synchronization to be able to retrieve chat history. 

You need to add "History" and "Synchronization" into your chat system design.   
1- How would chat and history would work. 
Does on refresh you get all history or X days back?   
2 - How different chat rooms work - group chats, disappearing messages, etc..  
---
As for your schema generate a unique User ID so you can identify properly users, not by pure name only.

Comment: i want to store them to db because it is on the requirements of my project :)